# select value from same row using case on table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a table like that in oracle:

[image]

Then I want to select customer_type and my new column named 'customer_id'. If customer_type is 'CORPORATE' then 'customer_id' column will filled with shipper_id else if customer_type is 'RETAIL' the column ('customer_id') will filled with shipper_phone.

This is my query:

```
select 
shipper_id,
shipper_name, 
customer_type,
case customer_type when 'RETAIL' then shipper_phone
when 'CORPORATE' then shipper_id
else 'Y'
from 
connote c 
inner join 
mst_customer mc 
on c.shipper_id = mc.customer_id ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `END` keyword in the **CASE** statement:

```
SELECT shipper_id,
  shipper_name,
  customer_type,
  CASE customer_type
    WHEN 'RETAIL'
    THEN shipper_phone
    WHEN 'CORPORATE'
    THEN shipper_id
    ELSE 'Y'
  END
FROM connote c
INNER JOIN mst_customer mc
ON c.shipper_id = mc.customer_id;
```

The same could be written using **DECODE** too:

```
SELECT shipper_id,
  shipper_name,
  customer_type,
  DECODE(customer_type, 
         'RETAIL',
          shipper_phone,
         'CORPORATE',
          shipper_id,
         'Y')
FROM connote c
INNER JOIN mst_customer mc
ON c.shipper_id = mc.customer_id;
```